# How to get viewId to use on another class?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a class to process ProgressBar.
But i cant find a way to transfer the viewId, which make null pointer error.

This the helperclass:

```
public class HelperProgressBar {
ProgressBar progressBar;
Activity activity;
int ID;

public HelperProgressBar(Activity activity, int ID) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.ID = ID;
    progressBar.findViewById(ID);
}

public void showProgressBar(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}

public void hideProgressBar(){
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}}
```

And this how i call it:

```
HelperProgressBar helperProgressBar = new HelperProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), progressBar.getId());
```

Comment: You have initialize the progress bar before setting its visibility in constructor.

Comment: Don't do such thing it leads to Memory leak . If you want to anyway make your helper class lifecycle Aware so it can nullify the Objects when your Activity is Destroyed . If you want to make it reusable in every Activity better option will be to create a BaseActivity and put this code in base Activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because progressBar is in your parent layout, not in progressBar.

Just pass the view so that you can handle it.

```
public HelperProgressBar(Activity activity, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor does not assign `progressBar`, only calls `progressBar.findViewById(ID)`